# Is Changed operator in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, order, operators

I am checking whether Order OwnerId is changed or not in Process buider.If Changed update related records.

But getting below error when Order.Close_Date__c is updated through Workflow field update when Order.order_Status__c is set to Closed.

> The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_old.OwnerId because it hasn't been set or assigned.

Here is the condition in process builder

[image]

It looks like [Is Changed operator](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/pages/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_ischanged.htm) is added recently in Spring 15.

Is it something related to this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dg6pAAC) which says process builder - Access to Owner Fields

Some helpful [link1](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000212174&language=en_US), [link2](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_troubleshoot.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: whats the criteria u used in immmediate actions of process builder to update related records ?  .. "Updated record meets all conditions" or "No criteria, just update records" ??

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because it's a new order. There is no old value to compare against. Change the process builder criteria to a formula which makes sure it doesn't fire if it is new.

```
Ischanged( [Order].OwnerId) && ! Isnew()
```

As an important side note, I often need to use formulas in process builder criteria for `Ischanged` and `Isnew` as Salesforce doesn't consider a new record to be a chanted record.

Answer (score 0):

U may have to deactivate your workflow rule which is doing field update when Order.order_Status__c is set to Closed.

Comment: Your solution sounds like it might be able to help get around this error message, but I imagine that the workflow rule was doing something important and can't simply be deactivated.